# Why jQuery Datatable not showing livicon icon in render function column?

Tags: jquery, datatable, icons, render

I need your help!
I have a jQuery Datatable that load data through ajax call to php page. The ajax call works correctly and the data is loaded. The table have other two columns (target first and last). In the last column is show an href with an livicon icon. This href is create with a render function than read a ID column value.
The problem is that the last column is not showing the livicon icon. Also if I try to use defaultContent options instead render function. 
This is my code:

```
    var table1 = $('#tblList').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/admin/addressbook/data",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    columns: [
        { data: null, sortable: false, className: 'details-control', defaultContent: '' },
        { data: 'id', name: 'id', visible: false },
        { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
        { data: 'mail', name: 'mail' },
        { data: null, sortable: false,
            render: function ( data, type, full, meta )
            {
               return "<a href='/admin/addressbook/show/" + full.id + "'> " +
                      "<i class='livicon' data-name='info' data-size='18' data-loop='true' data-c='#428BCA' data-hc='#428BCA' title='show'></i></a>";
            }
        }
    ],
    searching: false
});
```

The html result is this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class=" details-control"></td>
        <td>MEM Informatica S.r.l.</td>
        <td>Nuoro</td>
        <td>lblock@gmail.com</td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://hotline.web/admin/addressbook/show/3">
                <i class="livicon" data-name="info" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="view contact"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class=" details-control"></td><td>Treutel Ltd</td><td>Krajcikfort</td><td>E-mail: reyna.mosciski@ankunding.com<br>PEC: dickens.lenny@miller.com</td><td><strong>Ufficio</strong> (251) 338-8876 x628<br><strong>Ufficio</strong> 732.404.1733<br><strong>Fax (Ab.)</strong> 518.944.2509<br><strong>Fax (Uff.)</strong> (395) 363-7253</td><td><a href="http://hotline.web/admin/addressbook/show/7"><i class="livicon" data-name="info" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="view contact"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But the icon is not showing in the cell. Can anyone help me?

Comment: most probably either path or name of file is not getting constructed correctly

Comment: Can you give the complete html code with css and js includes?